# Склонение фамилии Гудонис

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли литовская фамилия Гудонис?

Answer (score 2):

Иноязычные фамилии мужчин склоняются, а фамилии женщин — нет:

Написал письмо своему другу *Валдас**у** Гудонис**у*** и его супруге *Анн**е** Гудонис*.

Comment: Соврем. женские литовские фамилии значительно отличаются от мужских. Они образуются от основы фамилии отца с помощью суффиксов -ут-, -айт-, и -ют-, а также окончания –е. Примеры: фамилия Орбакас для женщины звучит как Орбакайте, мужская фамилия Буткус преобразуется в женскую Буткуте, а фамилия Катилюс – в Катилюте. Замужние литовские женщины носят фамилию мужа с небольшими изменениями. К ней прибавляется суффикс -ен-, в редких случаях – суффиксы  -увен- и -ювен-, также окончание –е. Примеры фамилий: Варнене образована от Варнас, Гринювене образована от Гринюс, Гудонене - от Гудонис.

Comment: С литовскими фамилиями не все просто, поскольку правила образования женского варианта фамилии действуют в Литве. Если же семья живет, к примеру, в России, то женщина просто носит фамилию мужа без изменений. По крайней мере, такие случаи встречаются. И тогда  предложение "Написал письмо своему другу Валдасу Гудонису и его супруге Анне Гудонис" звучит абсолютно правильно.

Comment: В России с этими фамилиями тоже возможны варианты. Вспомните хотя бы Кристину Орбакайте. "-айте" - это признак незамужней женщины (на самом деле сейчас просто фамилии по отцу, женщина может состоять в браке, сохранив девичью фамилию). Точно так же можно добиться сохранения литовского варианта женской фамилии в браке. Другой вопрос - а кому оно надо, с российскими бюрократами бодаться?!

Answer (score 1):

Здесь такая трудность: носитель фамилии зачастую не готов согласиться с тем, что его фамилия склоняется. И никакие ссылки на правила русского языка помочь не могут: они разбиваются о "железный" довод — фамилия не русская.
Во всяком случае, в моей практике есть не менее десятка подобных, не увенчавшихся успехом, попыток.
Может, кто-нибудь поделится опытом: **как** убедить человека в том, что его фамилия склоняется?

Comment: Никак. Существующие правила сохраняют за человеком такое право. Я даже не о правилах делопроизводства, именно о русском языке. Право это оговорено на случай неблагозвучия или фонетических трудностей при склонении, но формальных критериев неблагозвучия нет. 

А на каком фронте Вм пришлось с этим столкнуться? Если при оформлении, скажем, дипломов или удостовернеий проще всего сказать, что в противном случае документ может быть признан недействительным. Хотя ситуация как раз обратная, трудности зачастую возникают как раз у тех, чья фамилия в документе склоняется по всем правилам.

Comment: А насчет нерускости фамилии - ну это просто. "Я на русском документ пишу, у меня все фамилии русские". Или "Перед законом все равны".  